# How do I prevent Skype notifications during a call

Tags: x11, notifications, skype

If I am on a Skype call with a person (with Share Screen Option switched ON), I don't want to get notified if someone calls me or messages me. They shouldn't know who my contacts are. What should I do in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

Depending on your distribution you could add a custom notification script. On e.g. Ubuntu you could use `inotify-send`. Add some short cut key combination to write *status* to a file.

E.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>

Then configure Skype to use this script instead of internal:

1. Select notifications
2. Enable *Advanced View*
3. Un-check *Display pop-up notification*
4. Enable *Execute the following script*
5. Enter path to script

[image]